# Calculating max and min array values is giving wrong results

Tags: php

I have this array with wind speeds:

```
 Array
(
[0] => 14
[1] => 15
[2] => 16
[3] => 11
[4] => 9
[5] => 7
[6] => 8
)
```

When I try to calculate max and min values, instead of the expected max=16 and min=7, it returns max=11 and min=9.
To make things even more difficult to understand, if the array is composed only of 2 digit wind speeds or only of 1 digit speeds, the max and min values are returned correctly, so this problem only occurs when there are 2 digit and 1 digit speed values at the same time in the array!

I tried many solutions found here like adding a leading zero, number formating, sorting the array, etc, but... no results!

The $wind_speed values are parsed from a json url like this

```
 {
     "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [
             -9.13,
             39.4,
             100
         ]
     },
     "properties": {
         "meta": {
             "updated_at": "2021-01-26T20:39:53Z",
             "units": {
                 "wind_speed": "km/h"
             }
         },
         "timeseries": [
             {
                 "time": "2021-01-26T22:00:00Z",
                 "data": {
                     "instant": {
                         "details": {
                             "wind_speed": 16
                         }
                     }
                 }
             },
             {
                 "time": "2021-01-26T23:00:00Z",
                 "data": {
                     "instant": {
                         "details": {
                             "wind_speed": 9
                         }
                     }
                 }
             },
             {
                 "time": "2021-01-27T00:00:00Z",
                 "data": {
                     "instant": {
                         "details": {
                             "wind_speed": 7
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         ]
     }
 }
```

From Json I get

```
 $decoded = json_decode($rawData, true); 
 $timeseries=$decoded['properties']['timeseries'];
 $total_events=count($timeseries);  

 for($k=0;$k<$total_events;$k++){       
 $wind_speed[$k]=$decoded['properties']['timeseries'][$k]['data']['instant']['details']['wind_speed']';
 ...
```

and then the array is created with a foreach loop,

```
 $i = 0;
 $wind= array();
 foreach ($wind_speed as $windt) {
 $wind[] = $windt;
 if(++$i > $total_events) break;
 }
 ....
 print_r($wind); // shows expected values and is correct

 echo(min($wind)); //shows correct result if array contains ONLY 2 digit or ONLY 1 digit wind speeds
 echo(max($wind)); // and shows wrong result if array contains BOTH 2 digit and 1 digit wind speeds
 ....
```

Is there any reason for this to happen?

Comment: In your provided code, I don't see a definition for $wind_speed

Comment: Might wanna make sure you run it as integers ( and is there maybe a period or comma in play )

Comment: Maybe casting to int would help. `$wind[] = (int)$windt;`

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](https://3v4l.org/RB8FU). Please supply actual values for `$wind_speed` and `$total_events` so that we may test.

Comment: You need to check your input because min/max would work against these array even if the numbers were incorrectly casted as strings: `min ([14, 15, 16, 11, 9, 7, 8]) => 7` and `max ([14, 15, 16, 11, 9, 7, 8])` => `16`

Comment: @MarkusZeller Shouldn't matter. Comparison is done numerically. See [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/bDg69).

Comment: Please share a full working example of that input array

Comment: @Russ J,  I have edited the post to show full example. Thanks

Comment: @El_Vanja, I have edited the post to show full example. Thanks

Comment: @Nico Haase, I have edited the post to show full example. Thanks

Comment: Even with the update, I cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the correct min/max:

```
<?php

$decoded = json_decode('{
     "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [
             -9.13,
             39.4,
             100
         ]
     },
     "properties": {
         "meta": {
             "updated_at": "2021-01-26T20:39:53Z",
             "units": {
                 "wind_speed": "km/h"
             }
         },
         "timeseries": [
             {
                 "time": "2021-01-26T22:00:00Z",
                 "data": {
                     "instant": {
                         "details": {
                             "wind_speed": 16
                         }
                     }
                 }
             },
             {
                 "time": "2021-01-26T23:00:00Z",
                 "data": {
                     "instant": {
                         "details": {
                             "wind_speed": 9
                         }
                     }
                 }
             },
             {
                 "time": "2021-01-27T00:00:00Z",
                 "data": {
                     "instant": {
                         "details": {
                             "wind_speed": 7
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         ]
     }
 }', true);

 $wind_speed = [];
 foreach ($decoded['properties']['timeseries'] as $item) {
    $wind_speed[] = $item['data']['instant']['details']['wind_speed'];
 }

 echo "Min -> ".min($wind_speed)."\n";
 echo "Max -> ".max($wind_speed)."\n";
```

Output is:

```
Min -> 7
Max -> 16
```

If for some reason you have a usecase that does not work, please give us the exact Json.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! And you were right because min/max would work against these array even if the numbers were incorrectly casted as strings. There was a problem in my inputs that was discovered and corrected when I implemented your solution.